# Mapping multiple rows representing a one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, json, database, mapping, record

Suppose a student -> book one-to-many relationship.[image]

When you query the related tables in Python, you would get the result in a flat format:

(Assume I'm using psycopg and raw SQL to fetch the records from DB)

```
records = [
    (1, "Student 1", 11, "Book 1"),
    (1, "Student 1", 12, "Book 2"),
    (1, "Student 1", 13, "Book 3"),
    (2, "Student 2", 21, "Book 4"),
    (2, "Student 2", 22, "Book 5"),
    ...
]
```

Note how related student -> book records appear in multiple rows.

In real world, such relationship could go multi-levels, say Student -> Books -> Authors -> Company.

What options are available in the Python ecosystem that allow me to convert a set of flat records from DB into structured objects or JSON, like so:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Student 1",
      "books": [
         {
           "id": 11,
           "name": "Book 1",
           "author": {            
             "id": 100,
             "name": "John Doe",
             "company": {
                "id": "...",
                "addresses": [
                    {...}
                    {...}
                ] 
             }
           }
         },
         {
           "id": 12,
           "name": "Book 12",
           ...
         },
         {
           "id": 13,
           "name": "Book 13",
           ... 
         },
         ...
      ]
   }
   ...
]
```

Notice how a set of related but flat data is consolidated into meaningful nested objects and collections above.

In the Java world, I used to solve this problem using the method explained here: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/jooq-tips-implementing-a-read-only-one-to-many-relationship/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What frameworks or libraries are you using? Could you show us some code to understand what what you have done so far?

Comment: What framework(s) will allow me accomplish what I need?

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at `SQLAlchemy`. It's a very solid ORM for Python.
But you'll have to implement the models and, by defining their serialization, you'll be able to get your desired json ouput.

Comment: ORM is out of question. In real life situations querying, filtering, sorting and shaping data from tables run in to 100s of lines of code which need the raw power of SQL. No ORM can match it in terms of expressibility  and efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic level solution, you can use defaultdict from collections

```
from collections import defaultdict

records = [
    (1, "Student 1", 11, "Book 1"),
    (1, "Student 1", 12, "Book 2"),
    (1, "Student 1", 13, "Book 3"),
    (2, "Student 2", 21, "Book 4"),
    (2, "Student 2", 22, "Book 5")
]

student2books = defaultdict(list)

for record in records:
    student_num, student_name, book_num, book_name = record
    student2books[student_name].append(book_name)
```

To add more details to the student or book you can use classes

```
class student_handler:
    def __init__(self, num, name): # you can add more fields as per your requirement
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
    
    def __str__(self): # you can customize name you want display on print
        return "student: " + str(self.num) + " - " + self.name
        # for higher python version -> return f"student: {self.num} - self.name"

class book_handler:
    def __init__(self, num, name):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "book: " + str(self.num) + " - " + self.name
```

Now you can combine both ideas, replace for loop with

```
student2books = defaultdict(list)
id2student = dict()
# extra variable to map student_num to student_handler
# creating new instance for every record will result in new hashcode and
# multiple student_handler instance will be created for same student

for record in records:
    student_num, student_name, book_num, book_name = record

    if student_num not in id2student:
        student = student_handler(student_num, student_name)
        id2student[student.num] = student # here student_num and student.num have same value, refer student class for explanation
    else: # sanity check to confirm student id always have same name
        assert id2student[student_num].name == student_name

    book = book_handler(book_num, book_name)
    student2books[student.num].append(book)
```

You can display results in the way you want, I am posting one example

```
for student in student2books:
    print(id2student[student], "holds following books")
    for num, book in enumerate(student2books[student]):
        print("\t", book)

""" will result in
student: 1 - Student 1 holds following books
     book: 11 - Book 1
     book: 12 - Book 2
     book: 13 - Book 3
student: 2 - Student 2 holds following books
     book: 21 - Book 4
     book: 22 - Book 5
"""
```

Comment: Thanks but this approach will not scale as I mentioned above in real world the nesting could be deep (Student -> Book -> Author -> Company). Is there a library that can get it done more generically? something like this https://simpleflatmapper.org/0106-getting-started-jooq.html (search for "SelectQueryMapper" on the page)